# How to select current Date in Selenium c#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, automation, xunit

I have calendar that need to select current date I have code but every time new month start then my code selects next day not current day. Thing is on my UI default day is next day shown.

```
IList<IWebElement> datePicker = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("element"));
foreach(IWebElement td in datePicker) 
{
    string date = td.Text;
    DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
    var todayDate = currentDate.Date.ToString("d");
    if(date.Equals(todayDate))
    {
        td.Click;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's really the issue here?

Comment: it not selecting the current date.

Comment: Share with us the URL